# Inserting ID in Textbox And Return Values Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am inserting ID of student in the textbox and i want to return all the values in different labels. If am using Three tables Students,Attend and Courses. SID of student is a foreign key in Attend And cID of courses have a foreign key in Attend Table. 
i am joining these three tables .

```
   Attend obJ = new Attend();
   Student oAd = new Student();
   oAd.sID = int.Parse(metroTextBox1.Text);

   var entryPoint = (from ep in dbContext.Attends
   join en in dbContext.Students on ep.sID equals en.sID join te 
   in dbContext.Courses on ep.cID equals te.cId
   where en.sID == oAd.sID
   select new{

      Name = en.First_Name,
      Course = te.Name,
      Presents=ep.Present,
      Absents=ep.Absent,
      });

            foreach (var iL in entryPoint) {

                metroLabel1.Text = iL.Name;
                metroLabel2.Text = iL.Course;
               metroLabel3.Text = iL.Absents.ToString();
               metroLabel4.Text = iL.Presents.ToString();

            }
```

the code is not giving any kind of response i want to show all though   it is not giving anykind of error

```
Student table Sid is in Attend Table
Course  table cID is in Attend Table
```

By joining these three tables i want to show which student has taken which course and what is the name of that course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by trying again and again i have found the answer how to join and get the fields of different classes from using foreach loop

```
        foreach (var eb in dbContext.Attends) {

            metroLabel3.Text= eb.Student.First_Name.ToString();

        }
```